# parent-child hierarchy with multiple parents in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I trying to make a parent-child hierarchy tree in Oracle 11g but with this condition

1. every **CODE is unique(no duplicate)** and has main parent in **PARENT_ID**
2. but there is an exception when **PARENT_ID IS LIKE '_999' then they have multiple parents that value is between ETC1 and ETC2**
3. Max Level Limit is 4

This is the tree that I intend to do:
[Flow Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP7OJ.png)

Below is the raw query for testing

```
with t as ( 
        select 'A1'    CODE, 'JOB_1_1' CODE_NM, 'A'    PARENT_ID, NULL ETC1, NULL ETC2 from dual union all 
        select 'A2'    CODE, 'JOB_1_2' CODE_NM, 'A'    PARENT_ID, NULL ETC1, NULL ETC2 from dual union all 
        select 'A3'    CODE, 'JOB_1_3' CODE_NM, 'A'    PARENT_ID, NULL ETC1, NULL ETC2 from dual union all 
        select 'B01'   CODE, 'JOB_2_1' CODE_NM, 'A1'   PARENT_ID, NULL ETC1, NULL ETC2 from dual union all 
        select 'B02'   CODE, 'JOB_2_2' CODE_NM, 'A2'   PARENT_ID, NULL ETC1, NULL ETC2 from dual union all 
        select 'B03'   CODE, 'JOB_2_3' CODE_NM, 'A3'   PARENT_ID, NULL ETC1, NULL ETC2 from dual union all 
        select 'C001'  CODE, 'JOB_3_1' CODE_NM, 'B01'  PARENT_ID, NULL ETC1, NULL ETC2 from dual union all 
        select 'C002'  CODE, 'JOB_3_2' CODE_NM, 'B02'  PARENT_ID, NULL ETC1, NULL ETC2 from dual union all 
        select 'C003'  CODE, 'JOB_3_3' CODE_NM, 'B03'  PARENT_ID, NULL ETC1, NULL ETC2 from dual union all 
        select 'D0001' CODE, 'JOB_4_1' CODE_NM, 'C999' PARENT_ID, 'C001' ETC1, 'C003' ETC2 from dual union all 
        select 'D0002' CODE, 'JOB_4_2' CODE_NM, 'C999' PARENT_ID, 'C001' ETC1, 'C003' ETC2 from dual union all 
        select 'D0003' CODE, 'JOB_4_3' CODE_NM, 'C999' PARENT_ID, 'C001' ETC1, 'C003' ETC2 from dual 
    ) 
 select * from t
```

What I already try

```
SELECT LPAD(' ', 4*(LEVEL-1)) ||  CODE AS CODE, CODE_NM, PARENT_ID, LEVEL
FROM    t 
START WITH PARENT_ID = 'A'
CONNECT BY PRIOR  CODE = PARENT_ID 
;
```

Result:

```
-- The result is as you expected, Data with 'C999' PARENT_CODE doesn't show Because not connected anywhere
| CODE       |CODE_NM | PARENT_ID|LEVEL|
| -----------| -------|----------|-----|
|A1          |JOB_1_1 | A        |1    |
|    B01     |JOB_2_1 | A1       |2    |
|        C001|JOB_3_1 | B01      |3    |
|A2          |JOB_1_2 | A        |1    |
|    B02     |JOB_2_2 | A2       |2    |
|        C002|JOB_3_2 | B02      |3    |
|A3          |JOB_1_3 | A        |1    |
|    B03     |JOB_2_3 | A3       |2    |
|        C003|JOB_3_3 | B03      |3    |
```

What I want is something like this:

```
| CODE           |CODE_NM | PARENT_ID|LEVEL|
| -----------    | -------|----------|-----|
|A1              |JOB_1_1 | A        |1    |
|    B01         |JOB_2_1 | A1       |2    |
|        C001    |JOB_3_1 | B01      |3    |
|           D0001|JOB_4_1 |          |4    |
|           D0002|JOB_4_2 |          |4    |
|           D0003|JOB_4_3 |          |4    |
|A2              |JOB_1_2 | A        |1    |
|    B02         |JOB_2_2 | A2       |2    |
|        C002    |JOB_3_2 | B02      |3    |
|           D0001|JOB_4_1 |          |4    |
|           D0002|JOB_4_2 |          |4    |
|           D0003|JOB_4_3 |          |4    |
|A3              |JOB_1_3 | A        |1    |
|    B03         |JOB_2_3 | A3       |2    |
|        C003    |JOB_3_3 | B03      |3    |
|           D0001|JOB_4_1 |          |4    |
|           D0002|JOB_4_2 |          |4    |
|           D0003|JOB_4_3 |          |4    |
```

All of the sources that I check have either have CODE duplicates in the table or just make a new Code to make different branching, **Any input on this issue will be very helpful, and thanks in advance**. My head already hurting because of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `OR` condition to the `CONNECT BY` clause to check if `PRIOR code BETWEEN etc1 and etc2`:

```sql
with t as ( 
        select 'A1'    CODE, 'JOB_1_1' CODE_NM, 'A'    PARENT_ID, NULL ETC1, NULL ETC2 from dual union all 
        select 'A2'    CODE, 'JOB_1_2' CODE_NM, 'A'    PARENT_ID, NULL ETC1, NULL ETC2 from dual union all 
        select 'A3'    CODE, 'JOB_1_3' CODE_NM, 'A'    PARENT_ID, NULL ETC1, NULL ETC2 from dual union all 
        select 'B01'   CODE, 'JOB_2_1' CODE_NM, 'A1'   PARENT_ID, NULL ETC1, NULL ETC2 from dual union all 
        select 'B02'   CODE, 'JOB_2_2' CODE_NM, 'A2'   PARENT_ID, NULL ETC1, NULL ETC2 from dual union all 
        select 'B03'   CODE, 'JOB_2_3' CODE_NM, 'A3'   PARENT_ID, NULL ETC1, NULL ETC2 from dual union all 
        select 'C001'  CODE, 'JOB_3_1' CODE_NM, 'B01'  PARENT_ID, NULL ETC1, NULL ETC2 from dual union all 
        select 'C002'  CODE, 'JOB_3_2' CODE_NM, 'B02'  PARENT_ID, NULL ETC1, NULL ETC2 from dual union all 
        select 'C003'  CODE, 'JOB_3_3' CODE_NM, 'B03'  PARENT_ID, NULL ETC1, NULL ETC2 from dual union all 
        select 'D0001' CODE, 'JOB_4_1' CODE_NM, 'C999' PARENT_ID, 'C001' ETC1, 'C003' ETC2 from dual union all 
        select 'D0002' CODE, 'JOB_4_2' CODE_NM, 'C999' PARENT_ID, 'C001' ETC1, 'C003' ETC2 from dual union all 
        select 'D0003' CODE, 'JOB_4_3' CODE_NM, 'C999' PARENT_ID, 'C001' ETC1, 'C003' ETC2 from dual 
    ) 
SELECT LPAD(' ', 4*(LEVEL-1)) ||  CODE AS CODE, CODE_NM, PARENT_ID, LEVEL
FROM    t 
START WITH PARENT_ID = 'A'
CONNECT BY
        PRIOR CODE = PARENT_ID
OR      PRIOR CODE BETWEEN ETC1 AND ETC2
;
```

Outputs:

> | CODE | CODE_NM | PARENT_ID | LEVEL |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | `A1` | JOB_1_1 | A | 1 |
> | `B01` | JOB_2_1 | A1 | 2 |
> | `C001` | JOB_3_1 | B01 | 3 |
> | `D0001` | JOB_4_1 | C999 | 4 |
> | `D0002` | JOB_4_2 | C999 | 4 |
> | `D0003` | JOB_4_3 | C999 | 4 |
> | `A2` | JOB_1_2 | A | 1 |
> | `B02` | JOB_2_2 | A2 | 2 |
> | `C002` | JOB_3_2 | B02 | 3 |
> | `D0001` | JOB_4_1 | C999 | 4 |
> | `D0002` | JOB_4_2 | C999 | 4 |
> | `D0003` | JOB_4_3 | C999 | 4 |
> | `A3` | JOB_1_3 | A | 1 |
> | `B03` | JOB_2_3 | A3 | 2 |
> | `C003` | JOB_3_3 | B03 | 3 |
> | `D0001` | JOB_4_1 | C999 | 4 |
> | `D0002` | JOB_4_2 | C999 | 4 |
> | `D0003` | JOB_4_3 | C999 | 4 |

If you want the `PARENT_ID` column to match with the prior level of the hierarchy then something like:

```sql
SELECT LPAD(' ', 4*(LEVEL-1)) ||  CODE AS CODE,
       CODE_NM,
       COALESCE(PRIOR code, parent_id) AS PARENT_ID,
       LEVEL
FROM    t 
START WITH PARENT_ID = 'A'
CONNECT BY
        PRIOR CODE = PARENT_ID
OR      PRIOR CODE BETWEEN ETC1 AND ETC2
;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=cad81a38fc6ae6dea6c3215636d485c1)*